# Install different modules by composer

Tags: php, composer-php

i need help. I'm a absolute newbie.

My repository (develop-branch) have some modules. Every module includes a composer.json.

```
repository (develop-branch)
    modules
        module_1
            - composer.json
        module_2
            -composer.json
        module_3
            -composer.json
```

composer.json from each module:

```
{
  "name": "xyz/module_1",
  "description": "module_1",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.6"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "XYZ\\MODULE_1\\": "../../../modules/xyz/module_1"
    }
  }
}
```

How can i install the modules (module_1 and module_3) via composer?

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "...",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://<path_to_repository>"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "xyz/module_1": "dev-develop",
    "xyz/module_3": "dev-develop",
  }
}
```

I hope somebody can help?

Thanks.

Comment: This basically looks fine, except for maybe your module_1 autoload path.  That should probably not go up and down the directory tree.  What's the issue your having?

Comment: It doesn't work. After composer update:

The requested package xyz/module_1 could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

How must the composer.json looks like in root, so that not all files are loaded, only the modules?